# Calling python script from bash script and getting it's return value

Tags: python, bash

I've bash script doing some tasks but I need to manipulate on string obtained from configuration (for simplification in this test it's hardcoded). This manipulation can be done easily in python but is not simple in bash, so I've written a script in python doing this tasks and returning a string (or ideally an array of strings).
I'm calling this python script in my bash script. Both scripts are in the same directory and this directory is added to environment variables. I'm testing it on Ubuntu 22.04.
My python script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def Get(input: str) -> list:
    #Doing tasks - arr is an output array
    return ' '.join(arr) #or ideally return arr
```

My bash script used to call the above python script

```
#!/bin/bash
ARR=("$(python -c "from test import Get; Get('val1, val2,val3')")")
echo $ARR
for ELEMENT in "${ARR[@]}"; do
  echo "$ELEMENT"
done
```

When I added print in python script for test purposes I got proper results, so the python script works correctly. But in the bash script I got simply empty line. I've tried also something like that: `ARR=("$(python -c "from test import Get; RES=Get('val1, val2,val3')")")` and the iterate over res and got the same response.
It seems like the bash script cannot handle the data returned by python.
How can I rewrite this scripts to properly get python script response in bash?
Is it possible to get the whole array or only the string?

Comment: Check this issue opened,   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767552/set-bash-variable-from-python-script ,   i think it my help you :) not sure if duplicate

Comment: `It seems like the bash script cannot handle the data returned by python.` Does the script __output__ anything? It just `RES=Get(` assigns a variable. Also your "python script below" _only_ defines a function, there is no output.

Comment: @KamilCuk what do you mean by "Also your "python script below" only defines a function, there is no output."? I've a function and call it in this bash script, this function has return. I printed the arr before returning it, so I know what is returned. Why do you think this script doesn't have output?

Comment: The python script, _as presented_, does not output anything. I do not know what is `import test` and I do not see a `Get` function defined, and `GetBranches` is not called and variable `arr` is undefined. Also, there is no `print()` in sight that would actually output anything. [MCVE]

Comment: @KamilCuk Sorry, my fault Get and GetBranches is the same function I've changed name to make it shorter, but forget to do so in python script.

Comment: Your *function* has a return value; your *script* does not. Your script can either write to a file handle/socket/etc, or provide an integer exit status reflecting its success or failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by exporting a string with elements separated by space.
I've also rewritten python code not to be a function but a script.

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
   input = sys.argv[1]
   #Doing tasks - arr is an output array
   for element in arr:
      print(element)

ARRAY=$(python script.py 'val1, val2,val3')
for ELEMENT in $ARRAY; do
    echo "$ELEMENT"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I rewrite this scripts to properly get python script response in bash?

**Serialize** the data from python side and **deserialize** on bash. Decide on proper **protocol** between the processes that would preserve any characters.

The best looks like it is to use newline or zero separated strings (protocol). Output delimiter separated elements from python (serialize) and read them properly on with readarray on bash side (deserialize).

```
$ tmp=$(python -c 'arr=[1,2,3]; print(*arr)')
$ readarray -t array <<<"$tmp"
$ declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3")
```

Or with zero separated stream. Note that Bash can't store zero bytes in variables, so we use redirection with process subtitution:

```
$ readarray -d '' -t array < <(python -c 'arr=[1,2,3]; print(*arr, sep="\0", end="")')
$ declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3")
```

Comment: Thank's for help, but here `declare -a array=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3")` you got 3 elements, and I don't know how many elements the output array will have (at least 1). How can it be more general to handle variable number of elements?

Comment: I do not understand. Do you understand what `print(*arr)` does? The code handles "generally variable number of elements" - there are one more elements than the count of separators in the input. The presented example python script has `arr=[1,2,3]`, so there are 3 elements. Change the python script to have more elements in the array, and you'll get more elements in bash array.

Comment: I'm now passing 3 variables to the python script becouse it's only test. The string passed to it will be read from file nad than the number of vars may (and will) vary, but there will always be at least one element.

Comment: Great - so do that!